# Are $\{ \alpha :\, \ker(\alpha) \subseteq V' \}$ and $\{ \alpha :\, \ker(\alpha) \supseteq V' \}$ subspaces of $\operatorname{Hom}_F(V,W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The question is given below:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$ and let $V'$ be a proper subspace of $V$. Are $\{ \alpha\in\operatorname{Hom}_F(V,W) :\, \ker(\alpha) \subseteq V' \}$ and $\{ \alpha\in\operatorname{Hom}_F(V,W) :\, \ker(\alpha) \supseteq V' \}$ subspaces of $\operatorname{Hom}_F(V,W)$?

**My questions:**

What is the importance of $\alpha$ being a linear transformation? How can I use this?
I know that $\operatorname{Hom}_F(V,W)$ is the set of all functions $f: V \rightarrow W$ that are linear transformations.

Also, I know that $\ker(\alpha) = \{ v \in V : \alpha (v) = 0_{W}\}$.

But I do not know how to use this piece of information to answer the question.

Comment: One of these doesn't even contain the zero.

Comment: I do not understand you, could you clarify please? why one of them does not contain zero?@Berci

Comment: I am here,I will try to write adetailed answer. You have been downvoted because your question does not have context.you should maybe include which textbook you are using and also what you know about the question. For example  , do you know the definition of kernel? Etc. இல்ல நா no chance

Comment: I am done you can check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you remember the question I answered previously. Even there, you had to check if some subset was a vector space or not.

The following is a rough-around-the-edges "checklist" on how you'd show that some subset, say $R$, is not a vector space :

- Every vector space has a zero element, so identify your zero element. If $R$ doesn't have the zero , then $R$ is not a vector space, so not a subspace.
- Suppose the zero element is not in $R$. Get a feel for what is in $R$, and what isn't. Even obvious examples help : for example, obviously $9$ is a multiple of $3$ and $1$ is not, but this observation could help you in some very non-trivial looking problem in the future! Obvious examples help you get a hand of possible general patterns that exist, which can give you counterexamples.
- Suppose $s,t \in R$ (not necessarily distinct). If $R$ were to be a subspace, then $s+t \in R$ should happen. However, if $s+t \notin R$, then $R$ is not a subspace. In a similar fashion, we take $s_1,s_2,...,s_n \in R$. If it so happens that $s_1+...+s_n \notin R$, then $R$ is not a subspace.
- If $s \in R$, then for any scalar $c$ we should have $cs \in R$. If for some $c$ it so happens that $cs \notin R$ then $R$ is not a subspace.

If you can't satisfy any of these conditions, then either your problem is quite difficult (and the one you've given is not) or $R$ is actually a subspace(!).

Kindly take out your notebook and write down this checklist. You will feel more confident when you approach questions with this list.

---

Let us knuckle down to work. $V'$ is a proper subspace of $V$. Let us call $S_1 = \{\alpha \in \hom(V,W) : \ker(\alpha) \subset V'\}$  and $S_2 = \{\alpha \in \hom(V,W) : \ker(\alpha) \supset V'\}$.

Let's go by the list. First, zero element.

Recall the zero transformation which I will call $\mathbf 0 : V \to W$ given by $\mathbf 0(v) = 0_W$ for all $v \in V$. We will check if it is in $S_1$ and/or in $S_2$.

What is the kernel of the $\mathbf{0}$ transformation? It is the set of all vectors which the transformation $\mathbf{0}$ sends to $0_W$. But then, $\mathbf{0}$ sends *all* vectors in $V$ to $0_W$, so of course $\ker(\mathbf{0}) = V$.

Now, we ask ourselves the questions which are asked for membership in $S_1$ and $S_2$.

For $S_1$ : Is $V \subset V'$? The answer is *no*, because $V'$ is a *proper* subspace of $V$, so $V \neq V'$, and therefore $V \subset V'$ is not possible. Thus, $\mathbf{0} \notin S_1$.

For $S_2$ : Is $V \supset V'$? The answer is *yes*, because $V'$ is a subspace of $V$ which is already given to us. Thus, $\mathbf{0} \in S_2$.

From the check , we see that $S_1$ is $\color{red}{\text{not}}$ a subspace!

But $S_2$ passed the first test. As we shall see, it will pass all the tests, because it is a subspace.

---

Let us proceed to verify that $S_2$ is a subspace. We just need two simple facts. I will leave you to prove these with hints, so you can tell me where exactly you are stuck.

> Fact $1$ : Let $\alpha , \beta \in \hom(V,W)$. Recall the definition of the linear transformation $\alpha + \beta$ as $(\alpha+\beta)(v) = \alpha(v) + \beta(v)$. Then $\ker(\alpha + \beta) \supset \ker(\alpha) \cap \ker(\beta)$.

Proof : In steps. Try the steps yourself, else hover over the yellow boxes to see the individual answers.

- Let $v \in \ker(\alpha) \cap \ker(\beta)$. What can you say about $\alpha(v)$ and $\beta(v)$?

> Since $v$ is in the kernels of both of these linear transformations, we have that $\alpha(v) = \beta(v) = 0_W$.

- From this, what can you say about $\alpha(v) + \beta(v)$?

> Since $0_W + 0_W = 0_W$, we get that $\alpha(v) + \beta(v) =0_W$.

- So, why is $v \in \ker(\alpha + \beta)$?

> Well, because $(\alpha+\beta)(v) = \alpha(v)  + \beta(v) = 0_W$, and now appeal to the definition of kernel.

Thus, fact $1$ is concluded. Now, suppose that $\alpha,\beta \in S_2$. Then $V' \subset \ker(\alpha)$ and $V' \subset \ker(\beta)$, therefore $V' \subset \ker(\alpha) \cap \ker(\beta) \subset \ker(\alpha + \beta)$. Therefore, $\alpha+\beta \in S_2$. This shows that $S_2$ is *closed under addition*.

---

For scalar multiplication, we have the following fact.

> Fact two : Let $c$ be a scalar and $\alpha \in \hom(V,W)$.Recall that $c\alpha \in \hom(V,W)$ is defined by $(c\alpha)(v) = c (\alpha(v))$ (i.e. first you do $\alpha$ then scale by $c$) .Then, $\ker(\alpha) \subset \ker (c \alpha)$.

Proof : In steps

- If $v \in \ker(\alpha)$, what is $\alpha(v)$?

> Haven't I said it enough? It's $0_W$.

- So, what is $c \alpha(v)$?

> What is $c 0_W$? Of course it is $0_W$.

- Conclude.

> Note that $(c\alpha)(v) = c 0_W = 0_W$, so $v \in \ker(c\alpha)$.

Therefore, if $\alpha \in S_2$ and $c$ is any scalar, we have $V \subset \ker(\alpha) \subset \ker(c \alpha)$ so $c\alpha \in S_2$. Thus $S_2$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Thus, $S_2$ $\color{green}{\text{is}}$ a subspace!

Comment: So you understood? Was the presentation fine?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is not and the second one is  a subspace.

Take $V=W$ and  $\alpha =-\beta =I$ where $I$ is the identity operator. Can you see why the first space need not contain $\alpha +\beta$?.

For the second one you only need the fact if $\alpha$ and $\beta$  vanish on $V'$ the so does $a \alpha+b\beta$ for any scalars $a$ and $b$.

Comment: for the first one, could you explain further please?

Comment: Also the second one I do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

*Sketch:* If $\iota_{V'}:V'\to V$ is the inclusion map and $\iota^*_{V'}$ is the map $f\mapsto f\circ\iota_{V'}$, then the second one is $\ker \iota^*_{V'}$. The first one not so much...

Comment: Could you please explain more details?

Comment: I will not.${}{}$

Comment: ok no problem .... that is enough

Answer (score 2):

Let $M:= \{\alpha \in Hom(V,W)| ker(\alpha) \subseteq V'\}.$

If $ \alpha \in M$ and $ \beta:=\alpha +(- \alpha)$, then $ \beta \notin M$, since $V'$ is a proper subspace of $V$.

Conclusion ?

Comment: What about the second?

Comment: Does proper subspace means it does not contain the identity ? or just it lacks some elements of the original space and those elements not necessarily specified?